# How to update a table with incrementally increased values where a column is null?

Tags: sql, postgresql, sql-update, window-functions

I have a table with two columns, `name` and `number`. Some values in the column `number` are null.

```
name | number
-------------
a    | 11  
b    | null   
c    | null
```

I want to find the max value in the column `number` and fill missing values with incrementally increased values, like the following table:

```
name | number
-------------
a    | 11  
b    | 12  
c    | 13
```

How can I do this in Postgresql?

Comment: An update to a table requires an UPDATE statement, which cannot SELECT column values.  Since UPDATE and SELECT are different operations, this cannot be done in one step, as you imply here.

Comment: Is name the primary key of the table, or is it unique?

Comment: @Dennis thanks. But I do not mind if it takes multiple steps.

Comment: @forpas we can assume it is primary. I would appreciate it if there is a general solution.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

For this sample data, you can use `MAX()` and `ROW_NUMBER()` window functions in a query that you can join to the table:

```
UPDATE tablename t1
SET number = t2.max_number + t2.rn
FROM (
  SELECT *,
         MAX(number) OVER () max_number,
         ROW_NUMBER() OVER (PARTITION BY number ORDER BY name) rn
  FROM tablename
) t2
WHERE t2.name = t1.name AND t1.number IS NULL;
```

See the [demo](https://dbfiddle.uk/?rdbms=postgres_12&fiddle=0a8370018fde12ad0ac0445879b1d7bc).

Just in case all numbers are `NULL`, change to:

```
SET number = COALESCE(t2.max_number, 0) + t2.rn
```

Comment: Thanks! May I ask if it is an efficient solution? In my case, I need to update 3M rows.

Comment: @Arman window functions provide better performance than other methods like subqueries and you do need a self join to update the table. In any case this is a general solution that you asked for and you can test it.